# Set sd card song as incomming message tone

Tags: android, sms, android-contacts

I have a issue regarding message tone change in my application.I need to change message tone for particular contact in phone (same as we use to set different ringtones for different contacts). So basically first i need to know that is it possible or not and if yes then give some hint to do. Thanks in advance. below is the code which is not working for me.

```
File k = new File(path, "mysong.mp3"); // path is a file to /sdcard/media/ringtone

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

//Insert it into the database
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = main.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
myActivity,
RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
newUri
);
```